# In R how do I get a list of all shared values between two data frames?

Tags: r, compare, dataframe

I am totally new to R so please forgive me, I feel like this is fairly easy but I can't work it out.

I have two data frames with columns named Genus and I want to extract a list of the Genera that are present in both sets. I would also like the opposite, a list of those Genera that are not shared between them, and know which sample they are coming from.

**Data1:**

```
ID   Genus  Count
1    Daphnia  10
2    Baetis   23
3    Berosus   2
4    Chimarra  5
```

**Data2:**

```
ID   Genus   Count
1    Calopteryx  5
2    Caenis      10
3    Baetis      3
4    Chimarra    12
```

Result:

```
Shared
------
Baetis
Chimarra

Unique
------
Calopteryx   Data2
Caenis       Data2
Daphnia      Data1
Berosus      Data1
```

Comment: look at `intersection` , `setdiff` and `union`. By the way format the data better or even better, post `dput(dataframe)` output here

Comment: Look at `merge` for shared by certain id and `match` for specific matching.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by format the data better? The actual data.frames have over 100 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared Genera

```
intersect(Data1$Genus, Data2$Genus)
```

Genera in Data1 but not in Data2

```
setdiff(Data1$Genus, Data2$Genus)
```

Genera in Data2 but not in Data1

```
setdiff(Data2$Genus, Data1$Genus)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That works great. So simple too.

Comment: if it answered please upvote and select as answer, it helps future searches and also helps answerer getting some reputation along the way helping others.